# With python and cherrypy, how do i read a txt file and display it to a page?

Tags: python, html, file-io, cherrypy

I have got a txt file in the format of:

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
```

I am trying to read it into a list and displaying it on to a web page just as it looks inside the txt file; one line under another. Here is my code

```
@cherrypy.expose
def readStatus(self):

    f = open("directory","r")
    lines = "\n".join(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    page += "<p>%s</p>" % (lines)
```

However, the output i have been getting is:

```
line_1 line_2 line_3
```

It would be great if someone could give me a hit as to what to do so line_1, line_2 and line_3 are displayed on 3 seperate lines inside the web browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrapping paragraph tags around all of the filenames. You probably meant to put paragraph tags around each filename individually:

```
with open("directory", "r") as f:
    page = "\n".join("<p>%s</p>" % line for line in f)
```

Or, more semantically, you could put it all in an unordered list:

```
with open("directory", "r") as f:
    page = '<ul>%s</ul>' % "\n".join("<li>%s</li>" % line for line in f)
```

Alternatively, you could put it all inside of a `pre` (preformatted text) tag:

```
with open('directory', 'r') as f:
    page = '<pre>%s</pre>' % f.read()
```

Additionally, you might want to consider escaping the filenames with [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) so browsers don't interpret any special characters in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just out of curiosity, what would i change if i want to say, only read the first 5 lines of the text file?

Comment: @Synia: For any of the ones that use `...for line in f`, you could use `list(f)[:5]` rather than `f`, or if the file is big and you only want a little bit of it, `itertools.islice(f, 0, 5)`.

Comment: so when i want to just take a little bit of the txt file, i would write `...for line in itertools.islice(f,0,5)` ?

Comment: @Synia: Yes, that should do it, provided you've imported [the `itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).